# Draw polygon on OpenLayers (WMS) and download data

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, openlayers, wms

The raster files are loaded into a PostGIS Database and connected to a WMS server, is there a good methodology to approach wherein a user can draw an AOI (Area of Interest i.e. a polygon) and download its attribute/.jpg/.img etc..

Basically similar to the [USGS EarthExplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), a small flowchart to easy the understanding, please correct me if I'am wrong in any technical details.

Raster--> PostGIS<--> WMS Server <--> OpenLayers/Leaflet <--> AOI --> Data Download

Comment: You can use a WCS request to download a subsection of a raster from GeoServer.

Comment: A WMS doesn't give you raw data, just a representation of the data.  If you want to have some data download you will need to use a standard that supports data download, such as WCS

Comment: @nmtoken Thank you for your answer! But what if I would like to download the attribute files? Such as the name, area etc. What would be the best way to go about that? The attribute information should pertain to the specific AOI only.

Comment: What attribute files?

Comment: @nmtoken Suppose the raster depicts the vegetation types of a region, the attribute would detail the classes of vegetation( Species, Count, Area, RGB values etc.). Thus drawing an AOI would allow to download the specific regional attribute for further analysis. It could be a .xls or .txt file along with the subset (.jpeg/.img)

Comment: Probably having some mental block, but in your WMS with your raster tiles in PostGIS how are you connecting those attributes?  In a vector data source the attributes are linked.  You can do a GetFeatureInfo for a point location and get all the associated attributes (you can't do it for a polygon, GetFeatureInfo doesn't work that way).  With a vector data source to get all attributes for a polygon selection you need to have a WFS, for a raster/coverage you need WCS.

Comment: @nmtoken Okay, I guess this WMS would create an issue. What if I use multiple layers (.img) format onto which I need to draw the AOI/ROI? Can a pythonic methodology be applied instead of .Js? I could hard code the path of the files which opens up a interface to draw the AOI and then download the report statistics?